# Why “modding out the homeomorphism” in the category Top makes no rigorous sense?

Tags: ct.category-theory

We can rigorously talk about Top, the category of all topological space, and also FTop, the category of all finite topological space. So I thought, we can define a category FTop', where we “mod out by homeomorphism” between objects in FTop. i.e. define the equivalence relation ~ in FTop as X ~ Y if they are homeomorphic and define FTop’ as FTop/~. But recently I am told that this “makes no rigorous sense”. Why is that?

Comment: What do you want to use as the morphisms from one homeomorphism-class of spaces to another?

Comment: How about this one: two continuous maps, f from W to X and g from Y to Z, are equivalent iff there exist homeomorphism p from W to Y and q from X to Z so that qf=gp ?

Comment: It does make rigorous sense. its just that it is a bad idea: the resulting category is a very weird object (the hom set in the resulting category are verry different from the hom set in the category of spaces)

Comment: What is true on the other hand is that there is an equivalence from any category to its skeleton, which identifies objects of the skeleton with isomorphism classes of objects. There is however no canonical choice of values of such equivalence on morphisms, just as there is no canonical choice of objects for the skeleton itself.

Comment: Composition of such "morphisms" (I mean, as in JASON's comment of 58 mins ago) is not well defined.

Comment: I don't understand this question. There are certainly algorithms which select a unique representative from each topological class of finite spaces (such algorithms are not efficient as long as I know, whatever this would mean).

Comment: 15 upvotes on an answer to a question with 0 upvotes? Provoking a meaningful answer is only possible with a meaningful question; I think both should be supported.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a couple of things to watch out for.

First, the collection of all spaces which are homeomorphic to a given space $X$ forms a [proper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)), and so we cannot just naively use set theory to form it. Nevertheless this is not a true obstacle, since we can employ [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).

Second, two spaces can be homeomorphic in many ways, which presents a problem when we try to define morphisms between equivalence classes. Writing $[X]$ for the homeomorphism class of $X$, what could the morphisms $[X] \to [Y]$ be? One might naively try to answer with "equivalence classes of continuous maps $f : X \to Y$ of some sort". However, this will not work so easily. Here's an obvious attemp that does not work. Given $X \cong X'$ and $Y \cong Y'$ and $f : X \to Y$ and $f' : X' \to Y'$, say that $f \cong f'$ if there are homeomorphisms $p : X \to X'$ and $q : Y \to Y'$ such that $f' \circ p = q \circ f$ (as suggested in the comments). Then composition of functions is not a congruence and so composition of morphisms is unclear (as noted in the comments).

As far as I can tell, the problem persists with finite spaces as well. If fact, the problem is not specific to topological spaces at all. As soon as there can be multiple isomorphisms between two objects, we'll have a problem.

One possible solution (which I initially called "standard" but people in the comments questioned it) is not to quotient the category but to pass to its [skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)), i.e., we form the full subcategory on chosen representatives of homeomorphism classes. In general this may require some form of the axiom of choice, but let's not worry about that today.

**Supplemental:** The discussion in the comments veered in the direction of homotopy type theory, so it might be worth looking at what happens there. If we take topological spaces to live at the level of 0-types (also known as h-sets), then by the [structure identity principle](https://books.google.si/books?id=LkDUKMv3yp0C&lpg=PP1&dq=homotopy%20type%20theory&pg=PA323#v=onepage&q&f=false) homeomorphic spaces are going to be equal. This may seem mistifying at first, for does such a statement not suffer from the same defect regarding morphisms, as above? No, because HoTT is proof-relevant. Concretely, suppose $h : X' \to X$ is a homeomorphism and $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map. The following does *not* work in HoTT:

> **Faulty HoTT reasoning:** Because $X'$ and $X$ are homeomorphic, by the structure identity principle $X' = X$, and since $f : X \to Y$ then also $f : X' \to Y$.

We must pay attention to *why* $X' = X$ (that's what proof relevance is about, proofs are mathematical objects, they're not just published stories and logicians' fetishes):

> Because $h : X' \to X$ is a homeomorphism, by the structure identity principle $\mathsf{sip}(h)$ proves $X = X'$. We may therefore transport any construction involving $X$ to one on $X'$ along $\mathsf{sip}(h)$. In particular, given $f : X \to Y$, there is $\mathsf{transport}_{\mathsf{sip}(h)}(f) : X' \to Y$. A little calculation reveals that $\mathsf{transport}_{\mathsf{sip}(h)}(f) = f \circ h$.

Note how instead of saying "isomorphic things are equal" we make things proof-relevant by saying "every isomorphism begets a proof of equality".

Comment: Great answer most of the way, but I’d quibble with the last claim, “The standard solution is not to quotient the category but to pass to its skeleton.”  That may be the *naïve* solution that people come up with when first encountering this situation — but surely the *standard* solution, in the sense of the solution followed by most workers and most of the literature, is to accept that one doesn’t really want the property “isomorphic objects are equal” after all, and be happy with the category **Top**.  [cont’d]

Comment: The issue underlying this is that while “isomorphic objects are equal” sounds appealing, it doesn’t really give anything useful.  What *does* have payoffs is the stronger “isomorphisms correspond to equalities” (or similar properties), but these have the significant cost of needing to move away classical category theory to a richer setting — e.g. to something like ∞-toposes or HoTT.  So these aren’t the “standard solution” either, at least not yet…

Comment: Is there a useful HoTT answer here? There should be (I am thinking of the structure identity principle).

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine: I don't think that the slogan "isomorphisms correspond to equalities" is really what HoTT (or similar systems) is about: calling those things "equalities" is just a way of saying: in HoTT "equalities" are not really equalities in the usual mathematical or philosophical sense (i.e. two *equal* things should be the *same* thing) but are the (iso)morphisms in an oo-groupoid. Rather, HoTT is about "equalities a=b are types as much as the objects a,b", which just means: (...)

Comment: Let me just point out the simplest example showing that composition of isomorphism classes of functions is not defined. If $A$ and $B$ are respectively a two-element set and a three-element set then there are two classes of maps $A\to B$ (constant map and injection) and two classes of maps $B\to A$ (constant map and surjection). Surjection composed with injection is a map $A\to A$ that may be constant or bijection, depending on choices of representatives.

Comment: (...)  there are terms for various things a,b, and  for every a,b there is a term for the "isom set" Isom(a,b), and the theory treats things like a and b on an equal footing as things like a=b. I think HoTT would look less "mystic" if the "identity terms" a=b were just denoted Isom(a,b) or just $a\cong b$.

Comment: @Qfwfq: Yes, on the whole I agree with you.  But “isomorphism corresponds to equality” is how one may get to the idea of univalence starting from the naïve idea many people have at some point of wanting isomorphic objects to be equal — and indeed, a slightly less naïve version of that is what originally led Voevodsky to univalence, as I understood his descriptions of how he got there.  (He described it as a pragmatic motivation when working in Coq, something along the lines of “I wanted to be able to reason with isomorphic objects as though they were equal.”)

Comment: I voted up, though I don't agree with the last paragraph :-)

Comment: You don't agree that it's a standard, or that it is a solution? Anyhow, I removed "standard" from the answer.

Comment: @Qfwfq: there is a sense in which equality in HoTT *is* in fact the usual mathematical equality. It's just that "usual mathematics" all happens at the level of 0-types (or h-sets) where the difference not really visible.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting additional paragraphs. Yet, I still have the impression that in HoTT what is called "equality" should really be called isomorphism. What would change in the theory if instead of $=$ one used the symbol $\cong$ and always spoke of isomorphism instead of equality? Suppose one has constructed the types A and B, and an explicit isom h between them; maybe there is some "non intensional" way to say $h\in\mathrm{Isom}(A,B)$, but it should be equivalent to prove the judjement $h\,: \,A=B$ (or $h\, : \, A\cong B$ in the other notation), right?

Comment: (forget about the use of the word "non intensional" in my last comment - it probably doesn't make sense there)

Comment: I think you are limiting yourself only to equality on the universe type, i.e., equality of types. But the equality type can be formed on anything, and we may for instance speak of equality between numbers. Surely you wouldn't call that sort of equality "isomorphism"? Regarding equality on the universe: first, you should call it *equivalence*, not *isomorphism*, see discussion at the beginning of Ch. 4 of HoTT book. Second, it is *impossible* to *equate* equivalence with equality, but they are *equivalent*. I hesitate to confound equivalent concepts, which is what you are suggesting.